# Balloon like UI element

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I want to create a button in my app that when tapped by the user, it will show some sort of balloon with some UI elements inside (it can be a button, a table, labels, etc). Something like the Add button (+) available in the Dropbox app for iPad (screenshot below):

[image]

Or this other "button" (actually it is a combo box) that I found in another app:

[image]

How difficult it's to create something like this with Monotouch? Does anybody know what's the proper name of this UI element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want to create is a ["`UIActionSheet`"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactionsheet).

E.G.

[image: An example from Google]
<sub>(source: [techfirm.co.jp](http://labs.techfirm.co.jp/ipad/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/dd2b56b3d488fd88de8d3906c66b5913.png))</sub>

[You can see and build from Apple; here's the UICatalog sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/uikit_catalog_creating_and_customizing_views_and_controls).

And [here's a catalog for Monotouch](http://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MonoCatalogSample) that should show you how to do it there.